# Validation Rule Limits For Standard Objects

Tags: validation

We are trying to combine validation rules in order to preserve limits.

I found in the documentation that custom objects are limited to 100 validation rules; however, I did not find any references that suggest this limit is the same for standard objects.

What is the limit on validation rules for standard objects? Is there an ORG wide limitation as well or is it strictly per object? Are there any articles on SalesForce that describe all of the limits within an ORG?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Standard Objects:**
In Salesforce Unlimited Edition you can have **500** Active validations rule.
In developer Org you can have **100** Active validation rules.

You can check these limits by

> Setup | Customise > ObjectName > Limits

[image]

Also all limits can be found in [Salesforce Limits Quick Reference Guide.](https://ap2.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Here's where to find the documentation by type of org in the Help:  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_general.htm&language=en_US. In an EE Org it's 100/per object. The limit is strictly on a per object basis.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick link to the Limits Doc which discusses the limits for most everything...

https://na27.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf

Specifically for validation rules, it depends on the org type. Unlimited is 500 per object, DE is 100 per object.